# Как передать значение одного класса другому в CSS

Tags: css

Проблема следующая, есть класс у которого назначен размер (ширина) по контенту.
необходимо в соседнем классе получить такую же ширину (как у первого) а не по своему контенту. При наследовании он просто наследует свойство max-content и становится равной ширине своего контента а не донора. Задача поставлена на чистый CSS без скрипта.

```css
.class1 {
width: max-content; /* Донор*/
}
.class2 {
width:              /*Сюда надо передать фактическое значение из .class1*/
```

Comment: Через CSS никак.

Answer (score 1):

В css этой возможности нет

Как вариант использовать препроцессор `scss (sass)` - `@extend`

Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/zj069c7r/

```
.class1 {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.class2 {
  @extend .class1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это точно можно реализовать на CSS как-то изящно,  и было решение, но оно "потерялось"... То что вы предлагаете не совсем понятно, как класс в таком случае динамически получит фактический width при эластичной компоновке?